# New to Workbench, How to go about making a simple table for inventory?

Tags: mysql, inventory, workbench

I am completely new to using MySQL Workbench and having trouble getting a simple inventory database. This is what I have got so far. As like I said I am completely new to SQL and Workbench. Yes, I am a student, but looking for more insight other than the little bit of info anyone can give.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Mon Feb 12 18:34:37 2018
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema inventory_manager
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema inventory_manager
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `inventory_manager` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `inventory_manager` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory_manager`.`Product_Used_Table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory_manager`.`Product_Used_Table` (
  `MUsed` INT NOT NULL,
  `MetalID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DeptID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `MUsedQuant` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MUsed`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory_manager`.`Product_Table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory_manager`.`Product_Table` (
  `MetalID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DeptID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `MColor` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `MLength` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL,
  `MQuant` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Product Used_MUsed` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MetalID`),
  INDEX `fk_Product_Table_Product Used1_idx` (`Product Used_MUsed` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Table_Product Used1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product Used_MUsed`)
    REFERENCES `inventory_manager`.`Product_Used_Table` (`MUsed`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inventory_manager`.`Department_Table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory_manager`.`Department_Table` (
  `DeptID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DeptName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Product_Table_MetalID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DeptID`),
  INDEX `fk_Department_Table_Product_Table1_idx` (`Product_Table_MetalID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Department_Table_Product_Table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Table_MetalID`)
    REFERENCES `inventory_manager`.`Product_Table` (`MetalID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Basically, I have 3 tables. One that will carry the product information, the next will have departments that use the product, and then one that will have what is needed to remove the product from the counts. No orders needed to put in, nothing of the sales sort. Just a simple database that allows for me to input the numbers when inventory comes in, or is going out or being used by said departments.

Comment: I presume you have mysql server up and running and can connect to it with Workbench?

Comment: Yes. I do. Everything is up and running. I'm simply looking for ideas to improve on this and make it function as a real inventory database.